# Texturing low poly mesh with textures from high poly model

Tags: texturing, uv

I made a few scans using Photoscan and they look decent. They are however made out of hundreds of thousands polys and I wanted to retopologize them.

To do that I took the obj file which was produced by Photoscan and processed in Instant Meshes. For me it did fantastic job. Reduced number of faces with preserved shapes. This is what I was looking for.

I would like to apply a textures to the low poly model. I do have a texture map exported with obj and mtl files, but I do not know how to transfer it to Instant Meshes output obj.

This is how high poly (400k faces) model looks like:

[image]

And this is low poly (53k) modification:

[image]

Instant meshes has done fantastic job as I said so I want to push it further. So I would like to use existing textures (visible on low poly model), bake them on low poly version, and retouch it a bit to look even better.

Can somebody give me tips what to do next? Which functions, modifiers etc should I use?

Comment: it could depend a but on the highpoly models and textures, you probably need to UV map your lowpoly model and map the texture over the UV map... sometimes you can bake normals/displacement from highpoly to visually transfer texture high details to lowpoly... try to show some example of what you have...

Comment: Thanks for comment. I've added the screens to show what I am working on. Hope this is enough...

You mentioned baking displacement/normals maps. This is definitely next step I'd like to go but still have no idea how. Any recommendations with regards to tutorials?